# I get an error while running an JS script with capybara/selenium/ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am new to Automation, I am using Selenium,ruby,capybara to execute this JS script and I get this error message,any help appreciated TIA 
Error message
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

page.execute_script('(function() {

```
function renderField($el, mode) {
  var limitMet,
      field = $el.data(\'add-field\'),
      section = $el.data(\'section\');

  window.DADI.editor.freeSections.forEach(function(freeSection) {
    if (section === freeSection.name) {
        freeSection.fields.forEach(function(sectionField) {
          if(field === sectionField.source) {
              var count = $(\'#section-\' + section).find(\'[data-field="\'+field+\'"]\').length;
          if (sectionField.max && count >= sectionField.max) {
              limitMet = true;
          }
          }
          }.bind(this))
          }
          }.bind(this))

          if (!limitMet) {

              if (!window.DADI.editor.types[field]) return false;

              var template = window.DADI.editor.types[field]._local.layouts.article[0].replace(\'.dust\', \'\');
              var html;
              if (template) {
                  var templateData = window.DADI.editor.types[field];
              templateData.params = window.DADI.editor.params,
                  templateData.free = true;
              templateData.fieldName = field;

              window.DADI.render.render(\'fields/\' + template, \'#section-\' + section, templateData, {mode: mode}, function (err, out) {


                if (err) {
                    html = err;
                } else {
                    html = $(out);

                if ($(\'.selectize\', html) && $(\'.selectize\', html).length) {
                    dadiSelect($(\'.selectize\', html));
                }

                if (html.attr(\'data-ql-editable\')) {
                    createEditor(html, 0);
                html.focus();
                }

                var fieldType = window.DADI.editor.types[field]._remote._publishType;
                var handler = window.DADI.editor.handlers[fieldType];

                if (handler && (typeof handler.initialiseField === \'function\')) {
                    handler.initialiseField(html);
                }
                }
                });

                return html;
                }
                }
                }

                # This takes the button (source) element and drops it into the target area and subsequently renders the appropriate cms fields.
                function simulateDragAndDrop(source, target)
                {
                    var $clone = source.clone();
                $(target).prepend($clone, target);
                if ($clone.hasClass(\'dadiCells-library__element\')) {
                    renderedHtml = renderField($clone, \'none\');
                $clone.replaceWith(renderedHtml);
                }
                }

                var source = $($(\'.dadiCells-library__element\')[1]); #E.g. The hero video button
                var target = $(\'#section-hero\'); #The target drop zone.
                    simulateDragAndDrop(source, target);

                })()')
```

Comment: '#' is not valid for comments in JS so that could be the reason for the error, however trying to use this much JS with `execute_script` is really abusing the method which is mainly designed for small one liners.  Using this much JS in a test would tend to indicate you're not really testing your app.

Comment: Thank you it did fix the pbm, Thomas, it did help! Also the normal drag and drop with Capybara/Selenium webdriver did not work hence have to use with JS, however thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. What fixed mine was replacing single backslahes `/` with double backslahes `//`